# Matplotlib with Pycharm does not run all the code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get the example program "Simple demo of a horizontal bar chart." to work. I am using widows 10, Pycharm with Anaconda. I have put print statements in to help debug this problem

```
    """
    Simple demo of a horizontal bar chart.
    """
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
    print("TEST1")

    # Example data
    people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
    y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
    performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
    error = np.random.rand(len(people))

    print("TEST2")
    plt.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
    plt.yticks(y_pos, people)
    plt.xlabel('Performance')
    plt.title('How fast do you want to go today?')

    print ("TEST3")
    plt.show()
```

the output in the run windows is:

```
    C:\Users\joe\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/joe/PycharmProjects/chart/chart.py
    TEST1
    TEST2

Process finished with exit code 2
```

To me it seems its not running any code after the print ("TEST2") I have put the print ("TEST3") after "plt.barh(y_pos, performance, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)" and its dose not print out in the output window as well.

The code as it is works in Linux with all 3 print statements being printed along with the graph window:

```
TEST1
TEST2
TEST3
```

All examples of matplotlib I try exit with "Process finished with exit code 2"?

Comment: I use matplotlib all the time with pycharm in windows ... I do not use anaconda however ... my guess is that anaconda is not playing nice somehow ... that exit code is not very helpful ... try adding more prints to figure out which line is actually crashing your program

Comment: Thanks for the reply 
I uninstalled Anaconda and installed pythonxy and it now works must of been a problem with anaconda for windows as it works perfect on my Linux machine.